# MS Access 365 - Synchronize table structure modifications in SharePoint

Tags: database, ms-access, office365

I recently uploaded my MS Access backend tables on Sharepoint site in order to share real time data to users of the frontend client with forms and reports.

Now I need to modify the structure of some tables adding some fields. To do that, I downloaded the necessary tables from Sharepoint and then I modified them. I tried to upload the new version on Sharepoint but the system didn't overwritten the older version. It created a new copy with a different name (e.g. `MyTable_2`). In this way, I'm not allow to use the newest table because the name is different and I should change the table name on every forms, reports and views that use it.

Could someone help me in how to push table structure modifications correctly on Sharepoint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about linked SharePoint tables in Access?

Then to add columns, you don't "download" the table(s) again, but in fact can use the Access table view to add additonal fields.

While you can't flip the table into "design" mode anymore when such tables are linked to SharePoint, you can most certainly add new columns by opening the table in Access.

Note that you can also add new columns by going to the SharePoint web site, but changes are far more easy done in Access.

So, from Access, just open the table, and use Click to Add in the last column.

This:

[image]

So, no downloading or local copy of the tables is required. You modify the linked table, and the new column will be added to the SharePoint site.

And you can of course open up the list on the site, and also use add column.

You don't want to download the data local, modify, and then try to update, since now you have a local table (un attached to SharePoint), and the existing live data table.

So, while a split database to SQL server, or a split database with a standard accDB back end? Yes, in those cases, you close down the front end, and open the back end, or use SQL server tools.

However, for SharePoint sites, you can add the new column, and you do that to the live linked table (list) you are using.

There is no table design mode, but as the above screen shot shows, the ability to add currency, or text or number columns still exists. You don't thus try to modify a copy of the table.

As noted, you can also make changes using the web interface on the SharePoint site, and Access will pick up the additional columns automatic for you.

Comment: It's clear, so publishing tables on sharepoint limits the opportunity to customize new fields. For example: adding a lookup with a related field of another table or decide the string type field length. Correct?

Comment: You can most certainly launch the lookup and table relationships from the add new field drop down. So you can thus add date ,number,  currency  or text.  And you can even add a multivalue column and one based on values from another table.  So I suppose some limitations exist,  but not many